# Wicket keeper move after bowl reach to him

Tags: rules, cricket

Can a wicket keeper move after bowl reach to him for stumping? Will it be a fair delivery?

Comment: What do you mean by the "bowl reach to him"?  All the fielders can move, that is what they are there for.

Comment: After or before? After, yes. Why not?

Answer (score 2):

I think the rules relevant to your question are under 27.3 and 27.4 of the MCC rules [here](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-wicket-keeper).

What I take from those is that:

- the wicketkeeper must remain behind the stumps until the ball strikes the striker or bat, passes the stumps, or the striker attempts to run. If this rule is broken, a **no ball** is called.
- in the time between a ball being bowled, and any of those 3 events occuring, the wicketkeeper cannot **significantly** alter their position. If they do, a **dead ball** is called. Exemptions to this rule are where the wicketkeeper is:

  - taking a few steps forwards to respond to a slower ball, **providing this does not bring them within reach of the wickets**
  - responding to lateral movement of the ball
  - responding an action from the striker suggesting the shot they will play

I think the first exemption there is most relevant to your question. If a wicketkeeper was standing back, and then moves up to the stumps as the ball is bowled to effect a stumping - I believe the umpire should call a **dead ball**. Otherwise, if umpire considers the keepers movement to be legitimate, the stumping should stand.